# why I can't set background color of view's underlaying Layer directly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I create a class named MyCustomLabel that is subclass of UIView, and I override it's layerClass function to return a CATextLayer class. I find that if I want to set the background color of that layer in layerWillDraw: function, I must set background color of this view first, or the background color is just black whatever I set to layer's background color.

```c
@interface MyCustomLabel : UIView

@end

@implementation MyCustomLabel

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // if I do not set it here, the final background color
        // is black, in layerWillDraw function, setting of layer's backgound color has no use
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CATextLayer class];
}

- (void)layerWillDraw:(CALayer *)layer {
    CATextLayer *textLayer = (CATextLayer *)layer;
    textLayer.fontSize = 20.f;
    textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
    textLayer.string = @"MyCustomLabel";
    textLayer.foregroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    textLayer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    textLayer.borderWidth = 5.f;

    textLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
}
```

Comment: What is the main thing you are trying to accomplish? Do you want to customize the appearance of your custom label?

Comment: why don't you subclass a UILabel?